# SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) when concatenating file contents with string then minifying with terser

Tags: javascript, node.js, concatenation, terser

I'm trying to read a file and save the file contents to a variable. I then want to use that variable and concatenate to it and parse it in other ways then minify it using terser but I keep getting an error:

> (node:13708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)

When I remove this line it works:

```
fileContents = 'String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){var j;var hexes = this.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];var back = "";for(j = 0; j<hexes.length; j++) {back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));}return back;}' + fileContents;
```

However the problem with removing this is that I will not be able to modify the string which is required. I also need to do this multiple times across the program then i want to minify and write the parsed complete output to the file. Here is the relevent code:

```js
var input = "input.txt";
function write(data) {
  if (!(output == undefined)) {
    fs.writeFile(output, data, (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  }
}

async function mini() {

  var { minify } = require("terser");
  var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(input).toString();
  fileContents = 'String.prototype.hexDecode = function(){var j;var hexes = this.match(/.{1,4}/g) || [];var back = "";for(j = 0; j<hexes.length; j++) {back += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexes[j], 16));}return back;}' + fileContents;


  var result = await minify(fileContents, { sourceMap: true });
  //write(fileContents);
  write(result.code)

}
```

Comment: `minify` trigger the error: who is this function?

Comment: It's from require("terser"); from the terser obfuscator docs https://github.com/terser/terser @ManuelSpigolon